# Elements $a,b\in L$ of degree $3$ over $K$ such that $a+b$ has degree $6$ over $K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

A finite field extension $L/K$ and elements $a,b\in L$ of degree $3$ over $K$ such that $a+b$ has degree $6$ over $K$. Can you give me an example about such field extension? Thanks.

Comment: *To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are*. That way, people won't tell you stuff you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help if you show that you've tried the problem yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $K=\mathbb{Q}$ and let $L$ be the splitting field of $x^3-2$ over $K$. Can you determine what $L$ is, prove that $[L:K]=6$, and find appropriate elements $a,b\in L$?